# Hide paypal payment button

Tags: paypal

I want to hide the paypal payment button. I am using the paypal Javascript SDK. I know I can use the disable-fundings to disable credit card and so on. But there is no option for paypal. I am using my own payment method selection before. I have tried with jQuery but it does not work:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".paypal-button-row.paypal-button-number-0" ).hide();
});
</script>
```

The paypal payment buttons are rendered by the Javascript SDK in a div called "paypal-button-container". That creates an iframe where all the payment buttons are in.

```
<div id="buttons-container" class="buttons-container"...
```

Inside that are other divs with the buttons. The button that I want to hide is this div:

```
<div class="paypal-button-row paypal-button-number-0 paypal-button-layout-vertical paypal-button-shape-rect paypal-button-number-multiple paypal-button-env-sandbox paypal-button-color-gold paypal-button-text-color-black paypal-logo-color-blue ...  ">
```

I think at first I have to go into the iframe and then find the element.
Currently I am trying this

```
if ($( "#paypal-button-container" ).contents().find(".paypal-button-row.paypal-button-number-0")) {
            console.log("found");
            $( ".paypal-button-row.paypal-button-number-0" ).hide();
        }
```

The console outputs "found". But it does not hide the div. Meanwhile I found out that the console always shows "found" even with a .find("abc").

Any ideas?

Comment: Without sharing more details, it's impossible to tell you how to do this. But any CSS selector that **matches** the button you want to hide (which you haven't shared so far) should be fine

Comment: If you **always** want to hide a given element, why not use static CSS for this?

Comment: That would be great. But it will not work as the iframe is coming from a different domain. I just tried this:
```$("iframe[id*='jsx-iframe']").on('load', function(){
        console.log("iframe loaded");
        $("iframe[id*='jsx-iframe']").contents().find(".paypal-button-number-0").hide();
    });```
And got this error: Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "..." from accessing a cross-origin frame.
It looks like it is impossible.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1):

It appears what you are actually looking for is [rendering standalone buttons.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/standalone-buttons/)

Note that presenting such independent/standalone buttons for e.g. radio button functionality or to use your own layout for the buttons is not to be used to avoid/hide presenting the PayPal option somewhere on the site with equal prominence to other payment methods. If you don't feature the PayPal payment method alongside other options the PayPal account's processing could be deactivated, since that's a violation of its TOS.

---

```
if ($( "#paypal-button-container" ).contents().find(".paypal-button-row.paypal-button-number-0"))
```

This approach shouldn't be used, but FYI the problem with that use of jQuery is you need to make use of `.length` after invoking it, and test against that. Note the difference:

```
if ( $('#myElement').length ) {
    console.log('#myElement was actually found')
}

if ( $('#myElement') ) {
    console.log('This will always be true regardless...')
}
```

It's probably also executing too soon, not after the buttons are fully rendered. But anyway there's no reason to do it this way, see the standalone buttons documentation above.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds great. With the standalone buttons it looks like it is working.
I have added the script for it.

```
var FUNDING_SOURCES = [
            paypal.FUNDING.<?php echo $paymentMethod; ?>
        ];

        // Loop over each funding source/payment method
        FUNDING_SOURCES.forEach(function(fundingSource) {

            // Initialize the buttons
            var button = paypal.Buttons({
                fundingSource: fundingSource
            });

            // Check if the button is eligible
            if (button.isEligible()) {

                // Render the standalone button for that funding source
                button.render('#paypal-button-container');
            }
        });
```

I will continue to test it.
Of course we offer also Paypal as payment method.

Answer (score -1):

For hide other buttons use this:

```
<script 
src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=EUR&disable-funding=card,sofort">
</script>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: What is "this"? Copying any JS snippet into a site might have unknown consequences